# what is the use of node.js in angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to Angular I am trying to understand what is the use of node.js in angular application

**docs**

> The Angular CLI, Angular applications, and Angular itself depend upon
>   features and functionality provided by libraries that are available as
>   npm packages.
>
> You can download and install these npm packages with the npm client,
>   which runs as a Node.js® application.

My question is we are using `node.js` just because `npm` is shipped with it or there are other reasons Based on my understanding `node.js` provides a runtime environment which lets you run javascript outside browser but we are not running angular application outside the browser it's running in browser so why `node.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2/4/5 is not dependent on any server side technology. You can use it independently.

In case of Angular CLI however, NPM Serves as a package managing tool for your Angular project AND it is dependent to Node.js.

Comment: Angular CLI also uses webpack, which packages up, transpiles/compiles, and optimizes your application.  All of these steps are run by JavaScript programs and they run outside the browser so you need node for them.

Comment: Thanx for your response